# Spring controller test path variable gives 404

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockmvc

I know this question has been asked here but I can't find an answer. I have a Spring REST controller endpoint that accepts path variables but I keep getting a 404 instead of 200.

Here's my controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/colorNames/{colorFamily}")
public ResponseEntity<List<ColorNameFamilyDTO>> getColorNamesByColorFamily(@PathVariable String colorFamily)
{
    List<ColorNameFamilyDTO> colorInformations = service.getColorNamesByColorFamily(colorFamily.toUpperCase());
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(colorInformations);
}
```

and my test is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(InfoController.class)
public class InfoControllerTest {
 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @MockBean
 private InfoService service;

 @Autowired
 private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Test
public void testGetColorNamesByFamily() throws Exception
{
    List<ColorNameFamilyDTO> colorInformations = new ArrayList<>();
    Mockito.when(service.getColorNamesByColorFamily(Mockito.anyString()))
    .thenReturn(colorInformations);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/colorNames/{colorFamily}", "Blue")
            .contentType("text/plain")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
}
```

I've tried use `param` and also specifying the string in the path directly. What's going wrong? I'm using SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE.

Adding a `doPrint()` shows up this on the console:

```
 MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /colorNames/Blue
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = [Content-Type:"text/plain"]
         Body = <no character encoding set>
  Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
         Type = com.controller.Controller
       Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.dto.ColorNameFamilyDTO>> com.controller.getColorNamesByColorFamily(java.lang.String)

 Async:
 Async started = false
 Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
         Type = null

ModelAndView:
    View name = null
         View = null
        Model = null

FlashMap:
   Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 404
Error message = null
      Headers = []
 Content type = null
         Body = 
Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
      Cookies = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use RequestBuilder object to call controller

```
 requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/colorNames/{colorFamily}", "Blue")
                    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

  mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andReturn();
```

print() will state you which api path you are calling

Update :

Please check controller and test classes

```
@RestController
public class AddDataController {

    @Autowired
    public AddDataService addDataService;

    @GetMapping(value = "colourNames/{pathVar}")
    public ResponseEntity dataAdded(@PathVariable String pathVar){
        return addDataService.printPathVariable(pathVar);
    }
}
```

and Test class should be

```
@WebMvcTest(AddDataController.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class AddDataControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    public AddDataService addDataService;

    @Autowired
    public MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void dataAdded() throws Exception {

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/colourNames/{pathVar}", "Blue")
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn();

    }
}
```

Can you share print() response here

Comment: Request URI is /colorNames/Blue

Comment: The request is Request URI = /colorNames/Blue but response is 404

Comment: Can you share print() response here

Comment: updated the question with the console response. I'm not sure if `print` produces a specific output.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no endpoint for ***"/colorNames"***, you will get HTTP 404. Therefore, check your controller. Your controller class should be marked with **@RestController** annotation.

Comment: Controller is marked with that annotation.